# Need to force specific resolution at boot

Tags: 13.04, server, xfce, lxde

Got a Ubuntu 13.04 server set up. Now I need to add a GUI so I can occasionally, at will (not every time) load a web browser to control a device. Problem is, it's in a rack in a lights-out server room and I must use a KVM-over-LAN device (Raritan Command Center) to control it.

Would strongly like to avoid the reinstall of the server, just want to add LXDE or XFCE (don't want overhead of GNOME or KDE) and a browser (FF or Chromium). Tried it once, LXDE came up in 1368-by-somethingoroher mode. Could not see the panel or launch any app because I could not scroll around in the Raritan to see that part of the screen, hadda do Ctrl-Shift-F1 to get to tty1 and uninstall the LXDE so I could get my server back.

So, here's the questions.

1) If I add a GUI in 13.04, can I call for it only when I want it, for LXDE came back up even if I rebooted. I want CLI all the time out of boot and GUI just on demand.
2) How can I make that GUI launch in 800x600 every time without fail, avoiding the higher-res modes which keep me from using it?

Thank you kindly, all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found the resolution code needed for GRUB, GRUB2 and LILO at http://linuxquestions.org/questions/blog/archtoad6-147095/… - added the code then updated grub, and on the next reboot, I got the resolution I needed. Now looking for the other solution, for GUI only on demand. The 800x600 code (256 color) to add in to /boot/grub/menu.lst is vga=771 .